# Problemas con entendiendo la gestión de documentos de laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Muchachos Necesito Ayuda Con un proyecto de laravel, Alguien que tenga el tiempo y las ganas de explicar la administración de archivos? Tengo un proyecto en laravel que guarda los archivos en mi public_html/storage (Dicha carpeta esta fuera de la carpeta de mi proyecto, ambas se encuentran al mismo nivel) ya que es la carpeta publica para gestionar todos los documentos, pero por alguna razon, esta molestan con la respuesta  mostrando el siguiente, error, Mi archivo de configuracion de FileSistem tambien lo adjunto, Segun yo esta bien definido el Link Pero para ser Honesto, Nunca termine de entender bien como funcionaba, ya que algunas veces funciona y otras veces no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]